# iOS UIWebView: Reliable way to clear all local/sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, ios, html, swift, uiwebview

I have an iOS app where I need to clear all `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` data set by its UIWebView. I cannot use `localStorage.clear()` in my web app because the UIWebView I use loads data from across multiple domains, and I need to logout of every single one of them.

Is there any straightforward way to do this? I can't find specific documentation on it and although some posts have suggested the following code, it doesn't work for all of my users' devices.

```
    NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
    NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().diskCapacity = 0
    NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().memoryCapacity = 0
```